# How to cut the upper part of the plot?

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,8) node[left] {$y$}; 
\foreach \a in {0,...,5}
    \draw[scale=1,domain=1:3,smooth,variable=\x,purple]  plot ({\x},{\x*\x +1 + \a*(\x-2)*(\x-4)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why is it happening? I need to cut the upper part of the plot.

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider the `pgfplots` package, which offers various ways to restrict the domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Easy ad-hoc solution:**

(the command used is pretty self-explanatory: think of it as taking a rectangular selection in Photoshop and deleting everything outside of it)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,8) node[left] {$y$};
\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (5,8);
    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}
        \draw[scale=1,domain=1:3,smooth,variable=\x,purple]  plot ({\x},{\x*\x +1 + \a*(\x-2)*(\x-4)});
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

But there are "cleaner" ways to cut off the upper part. I would suggest you take a look at the `axis`-environment from `pgfplots` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You marked it as `pgfplots` but using TikZ syntax. Here is a pgfplots example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,domain=1:3,no marks,axis lines=middle,enlargelimits]
\foreach \a in {0,...,5}
    \addplot[purple] plot (x,{x^2 +1 + \a*(x-2)*(x-4)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]